# Appending to lists/adding keys to a variable in ansible

Tags: arrays, json, ansible

I'm following as per [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/685673/appending-to-lists-or-adding-keys-to-dictionaries-in-ansible) to append variables to a list in Ansible; i'm using logic `my_group: {{my_group + [item.hostname]}}`

```
- name: "Initialize variables"
  set_fact:
      my_group: []

- set_fact:
      my_group:
        "{% if item.hostGroup == "webgroup" %}
           {{my_group + [item.hostname]}}
        {% endif %}"
  with_items: "{{serverList}}"
```

my `serverList` payload looks like

```
{
    "hostGroup": "dbgroup", 
    "hostname": "db_server_usa_01" 
}, 
{
    "hostGroup": "webgroup", 
    "hostname": "web_server_usa_01" 
}
```

Getting an error like below

```
"Unexpected templating type error occurred on 
({% if item.hostGroup == 'webgroup' %} {{my_group + [item.hostname]}} 
{% endif %}): coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found"}
```

It works perfectly if there is NO `if` loop.  Any idea how to make this work with `if` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't this look nicer?

```
- name: "Initialize variables"
  set_fact:
      my_group: "{{ serverList | selectattr('hostGroup','equalto','webgroup') | map(attribute='hostname') | list }}"
```

Comment: Very elegant solution, even if some explanation would have been even nicer. :)